# Android: StaggeredGridLayoutManager scroll to top while initializing

Tags: android, gridlayoutmanager

I'm using [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html) for my image gallery. I've set `setReverseLayout(true)`, so that images get stacked from bottom.

The problem I'm facing is that at initialization of app, the scroll points at bottom of gallery. I would want the scroll to be at the top of the gallery when user first starts the app.

I've tried using `scrollToPosition` (the following code snippet) but then the scroll ends up somewhere in middle of gallery, probably because the images haven't loaded up properly at the time of calling `scrollToPosition`.

```
mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);

mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
mImageList = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getImages();
adapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(),mImageList);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mImageList.size()-1);
```

Is there a proper way to point the scroll at the top, rather than at the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved similar problem before and here is method:

```
mRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        ViewTreeObserver observer = mRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver();
                        scrollRecyclerViewToTop();
                        if (!observer.isAlive()) {
                            return;
                        }
                        if (mScrolledByUser) {
                            if (hasJellyBeanApi()) {
                                observer.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                            } else {
                                observer.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

And:

```
mRecyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        mScrollByUser = true;
        return false;
    }
});
```

And:

```
private void scrollRecyclerViewToTop() {
    mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
    mRecyclerView.scrollBy(0, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
}
```

The meaning is easy: let `RecyclerView` always scroll to top until user touches it. Hope this can help you.

Comment: it works when i touch the screen but nothing shows up if i dont touch. I want to scroll it by default that is user doesnt required to touch. This is the closest answer so i will award bounty for you. btw my answer works as i want.

Answer (score 1):

try finding the first visible position by calling
[findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPositions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html#findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPositions(int[]))

or [findFirstVisibleItemPositions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html#findFirstVisibleItemPositions(int[]))

the call your recycler view scrollToPosition with the position obtained from the previous method(s)

Comment: That won't solve the problem completely. The first visible item will not always be the last item. So I may end up scrolling to different positions on different runs.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `scrollToPositionWithOffset()` function of `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` instead. I found it more reliable than `scrollToPosition`. Also make sure that you execute this function inside `Handler().post()`. This will cause the `Runnable`  to be added to the message queue. It will run once the UI thread is free.

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                staggeredGridLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(mImageList.size() - 1, 0);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt work for me. Thansk for the answer

Answer (score 1):

I used scrolltoposition inside dataobserver and now it works fine..

When the recyclerview loads, items on top are visible with the below code:

```
rcAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
                int count = rcAdapter.getItemCount();
                mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(itemCount-1);

            }
        });
```

to scroll to the bottom for newly added items as in the chat view, use below code.

```
     rcAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                        super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
                        int count = rcAdapter.getItemCount();
                        int lastVisiblePositions[] = new int[2]; //for 2 columns
                        int lastVisiblePosition = staggeredGridLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPositions(lastVisiblePositions)[0];
                        // If the recycler view is initially being loaded or the user is at the bottom of the list, scroll
                        // to the bottom of the list to show the newly added message.
                        if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 ||
                            (positionStart >= (count- 1) && lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart - 1))) {
                           mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(positionStart);
                        }

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you,I also used this link in code

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView

> Every AdapterView (such as ListView and GridView) has support for
>   binding to the OnScrollListener events which are triggered whenever a
>   The  user scrolls through the collection. Using this system, we can define
>   a basic EndlessScrollListener which supports most use cases by
>   creating our own class that extends OnScrollListener:

```
public abstract class EndlessScrollListener implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
    // The minimum number of items to have below your current scroll position
    // before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    // The current offset index of data you have loaded
    private int currentPage = 0;
    // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
    private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
    // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
    private boolean loading = true;
    // Sets the starting page index
    private int startingPageIndex = 0;

    public EndlessScrollListener() {
    }

    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
        this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
    }

    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold, int startPage) {
        this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
        this.startingPageIndex = startPage;
        this.currentPage = startPage;
    }

    // This happens many times a second during a scroll, so be wary of the code you place here.
    // We are given a few useful parameters to help us work out if we need to load some more data,
    // but first we check if we are waiting for the previous load to finish.
    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) 
  {
        // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
        // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state
        if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
            this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
            this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            if (totalItemCount == 0) { this.loading = true; } 
        }
        // If it's still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has
        // changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the current page
        // number and total item count.
        if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
            loading = false;
            previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            currentPage++;
        }

        // If it isn't currently loading, we check to see if we have breached
        // the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data.
        // If we do need to reload some more data, we execute onLoadMore to fetch the data.
        if (!loading && (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount + visibleThreshold) >= totalItemCount ) {
         loading = onLoadMore(currentPage + 1, totalItemCount);
        }
    }

    // Defines the process for actually loading more data based on page
    // Returns true if more data is being loaded; returns false if there is no more data to load.
    public abstract boolean onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount);

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // Don't take any action on changed
    }
  }
```